# Prove or disprove that the set  is closed in metric space ( [ −1 , 1 ] , ∞ ) where ∞(  ,  ) = sup −1≤  ≤1 | () − ()

Tags: general-topology

Let  = {  ∈ [−1 , 1] ∶ 2 ≤ (0) ≤ 4 }

My idea is to use the fact that for each closed set  in (  , ) , the preimage −1[  ] is closed in metric space (,).  We have the set A is all the continuous function in the interval [-1,1], how can we use this in the proof?

By looking at similar questions, is the boundary set is A itself? Otherwise , how do we find the boundary set?

Comment: $A$ is not its own boundary. Any function $f$ with $2 <f(0)<4$ is an interior point of $A$.

Comment: So is the boundary set be {  ∈ [−1 , 1] ∶ (0) = 2 }U{  ∈ [−1 , 1] ∶ (0) =4 }? Does this expression make sense?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the boundary.

Answer (score 2):

Define $\phi : C[-1,1] \to \mathbb R$ by $\phi(f) = f(0)$. Note that $|\phi(f)-\phi(g)| \leq d_\infty(f,g)$ for every $f$ and $g$ in $C[-1,1]$. Thus, $\phi$ is continuous and then $A = \phi^{-1}([2,4])$ is closed in $(C[-1,1],d_\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = \{f \in C[-1, 1] : 2 \leq f(0) \leq 4 \}$. We'll show this is closed by showing that the complement is open. Suppose $f \in A^{c}$. Then $f(0) > 4$ or $f(0) < 2$. In either case, there is some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(f(0) - \epsilon , f(0) + \epsilon) \cap [2 , 4] = \emptyset$. This should be intuitive, but rigorously, this follows because $[2, 4]$ itself is a closed subset of the reals. Anyway, then consider the ball $B(f, \epsilon)$. If $g \in B(f, \epsilon)$, then $sup_{|t| \leq 1}|f(t) - g(t)| < \epsilon.$ In particular, then, $|f(0) - g(0)| < \epsilon$. So then $g(0) \in (f(0) - \epsilon,f(0) + \epsilon)$, so that $g(0) \not \in [2, 4]$, as $(f(0) - \epsilon, f(0) + \epsilon) \cap [2, 4] = \emptyset$. This means $B(f, \epsilon) \subseteq A^c$. As $f$ was arbitrary, this means that $A^c$ is open, and thus $A$ is closed.

Comment: And in fact we can easily choose $\epsilon$ explicitly as, for example, $\max(f(0) - 4, 2 - f(0)) / 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(f_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ be a convergent sequence of members of $A,$ converging to $g.$  For any $n\in \Bbb N$ we have $|f_n(0)-g(0)|\le d(f_n,g).$ And $d(f_n,g)\to 0,$ so $f_n(0)-g(0)\to 0.$ So $g(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(0)\in [2,4]$ because every $f_n(0)\in [2,4]$ and $[2,4]$ is closed in $\Bbb R.$ So $g\in A.$